# C# Reporting Error in Processing 'Illegal Path'

Tags: c#, rdlc, reportviewer, embedded-resource

I am trying to get reporting in C# to work. I'm trying to embed my rdlc file as such:

```
var reportDataSource = new ReportDataSource("ProspectsDataSet", _allProspects);
ReportViewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(reportDataSource);

ReportViewer.LocalReport.ReportEmbeddedResource = "SdcDatabase.Modules.EnquiryModule.View.Reports.ProspectsReport.rdlc";
ReportViewer.ZoomMode = ZoomMode.PageWidth;
ReportViewer.RefreshReport();
```

The build action on the rdlc file itself is set to embedded resource and the copy to output directory set to copy always.

I have double checked and I'm certain that that is the correct namespace in the ReportEmbeddedResource string. However when I try to load the report I get this error:

[image]

I have tried switching a few things around in the path, such as replacing '.' with '/' and '\' but so far I have not been able to get anything to fix this. I have also tried using LocalPath instead of EmbeddedResource but again I come across errors.

I have searched for this issue but haven't found anything to resolve my issue thus far.

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/7b259014-9bb2-424a-9c5b-37be2fcb1bef/how-to-use-reportembeddedresource-in-reportviewer-webform-control?forum=vsreportcontrols

Answer (score 0):

I have a reporting wrapper class that works well for my apps.  I have a property to hold the name of the ".rdlc" report definition I want to run.  Then, when I call my "RunReport()" method, I assign the report based on reading a stream from my application assembly resource.  A short version for what you have might be

```
ReportViewer.LocalReport.LoadReportDefinition( GetRDLCStream( "ProspectsReport.rdlc" ));
```

Then, lower, I have a method

```
private Stream GetRDLCStream( string rptRDLC)
{
   var stream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream(
                    "SdcDatabase.Modules.EnquiryModule.View.Reports." + rptRDLC);

   return stream;
}
```

Obviously, I am not positive of the naming convention of your path to your project but am implying the above path.  However, it should reflect (for example)

```
   "NameOfYourApp.SubFolderWithinPath.MaybeReportsSubFolder." + actualReport.RDLC name
```

This way, I never have to worry about copying out a resource and hoping the paths work.  I know it is embedded and where within the assembly.